# Given $\lvert f''(x)\vert \leq m$ on $[0,a]$, show that $\lvert f'(0)\vert + \lvert f'(a) \rvert \leq am.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

> Problem:Assume that $|f''(x)| \leq  m$ for each $x$ in the interval $[0, a]$, and assume that $f$ takes on its largest value at an interior point of this interval. Show that $|f'(0)| + |f'(a)| \leq am$. You may assume
>   that $f''$ is continuous in $[0, a]$.

**I do**. $|\int_{0}^{a} f''(x) dx| \leq \int_{0}^{a} |f''(x)| dx \leq \int_{0}^{a} m dx = am$ then I got  $|f'(a)-f'(0)|\leq am$.
now if I could do $|f'(a)|+|f'(0)|\leq|f'(a)-f'(0)| \ $ and do not know how to use the information they give me to resolve this.

Comment: Hint: Suppose $x\in(0,a)$ is where $f$ takes on its largest value. Express $f'(0)$ and $f'(a)$ in terms of integrals from $x$ to $0$ and $a$, respectively.

Comment: Ahh. ok. $|\int_{0}^{x} + \int_{x}^{a}| \leq |\int_{0}^{x}|+|\int_{x}^{a}|$

Comment: I mean, you don't really have to consider $\int_0^x+\int_x^a$, just the values of $\int_0^x$ and $\int_x^a$ separately. But I think you're on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\rho \in (0, a)$ maximizes $f$ on the interval $[0,a]$. Then
$$ \left \lvert \int_0^\rho f''(x) dx \right \rvert= \lvert f'(\rho) - f'(0)\rvert = \lvert f'(0) \rvert,$$
where we used that $f'(\rho) = 0$. On the other hand,
$$ \left\lvert \int_0^\rho f''(x)dx \right\rvert \leq \int_0^\rho \lvert f''(x)\rvert \leq \rho m.$$
Together, these indicate that
$$ \lvert f'(0)\rvert \leq \rho m.$$
A similar analysis on $\displaystyle \int_\rho^a f''(x)dx$ shows that
$$ \lvert f'(a)\rvert \leq (a-\rho)m.$$
Adding these two bounds together, we see that
$$ \lvert f'(0) \rvert + \lvert f'(a) \rvert \leq \rho m + (a - \rho)m = am,$$
as was to be shown.$\diamondsuit$

Comment: You assumed that if $f$ is twice differentiable, then $f''$ is twice integrable-- that doesn't necessarily hold, does it?   if $f$ is twice differentiable, then $f''$ has an antiderivative-that doesn't necessarily mean its integrable. Or does it, in this particular case?

Comment: Where do I use that $f''$ is twice integrable? I believe I only use that $f''$ is once integrable, which is true as $f''$ is given to be continuous.